# AngularJS - Showing error message when default dropdown option keeps selected

Tags: angularjs, html

I want to show an error to the user whenever he/she interacts with a dropdown selector and does not select anything.

I've got this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label" translate="contacta.form.contact" for="field_contact">Modo de contacto preferido</label> 
      <select id="field_contact" name="contact" required 
         class="form-control form-control-200" ng-model="vm.form.contact" style="min-width: 250px">
         <option disabled selected value style="display:none"
            translate="contacta.form.select.default"> -- Select an option -- </option>
         <option value="email"
            translate="contacta.form.select.selectemail">E-Mail</option>
         <option value="telefon"
            translate="contacta.form.select.selectphone">TelÃ©fono</option>
      </select>
      <div ng-show="contactaForm.contact.$invalid && contactaForm.contact.$dirty">
         <p class="help-block" ng-show="contactaForm.contact.$error.required" translate="contacta.form.validation.required">This field is required.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that, whenever user clicks on the dropdown (being default value "-- Select an option --") and does not click neither of the available values ("E-Mail" or "Phone"), an error should display below the field with a "This field is required" string.

So far, it's not working.

Comment: remove selected attribute from that and try

Comment: but will `$dirty` be true if you don't touch it and just hit submit?

Comment: @JYoThI yes, that did the trick :) However, no red inline shows with the error. Just regular gray text color.

Comment: remove disabled attribute too

Comment: @JYoThI Still not working. Nevertheless, it's another issue. If you want to write an answer, I'll mark it as correct :)

Comment: problem is resolved ?

Comment: @JYoThI Yes, it is.